# Notice Undefined Index while trying to pass jQuery Array to PHP through Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using Dual listbox extension in my **Yii2** Project. And I'm trying to add the selected `item` to a new array `var dataArray = []` using *push* **jQuery** method and then I want to pass the `dataArray` to **PHP** file through *ajax*. I've just learning jQuery for 4 days, but I still don't know exactly where I've to put my code for *push* and pass the `dataArray`. But I still try to figure out.

This is the codes

### jQuery

jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js

```
function removeAll(dualListbox) {
    if (dualListbox.settings.preserveSelectionOnMove === 'all' && !dualListbox.settings.moveOnSelect) {
        saveSelections(dualListbox, 1);
        saveSelections(dualListbox, 2);
    } else if (dualListbox.settings.preserveSelectionOnMove === 'moved' && !dualListbox.settings.moveOnSelect) {
        saveSelections(dualListbox, 2);
    }

    dualListbox.element.find('option').each(function(index, item) {
        var $item = $(item);
        var dataArray = [];
        if (!$item.data('filtered2')) {
            dataArray.push($item);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../../../views/customize-header/index.php',
                data: {dataArray: dataArray},
                success: function() {
                    alert('ok');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    refreshSelects(dualListbox);
    triggerChangeEvent(dualListbox);
}
```

### PHP

index.php

```
<?php
   $myArray = $_POST['dataArray'];
   print_r($myArray);
die();   
?>
```

But I got this error:

> Undefined index: dataArray
>   [image]

Anybody can help me check the code or help to solve the proble?
Or anybody ever got the same error? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why does your code block contain `$_POST['dataArray']` and your screenshot: `$_POST['akhirArray']`. You clearly post it to your `index.php` with the dataArray key. So shouldn't you change the akhirArray to dataArray? If this page is also available from the GET verb, to post your data, than you should check whether the value `isset()` else it is never defined.

Comment: @Kwido Sorry, I've make a mistake. So did I've been set the code in right place? I don't understand, can you describe ?